# How to get the current value of a field or property passed to constructor, without using reflection

Tags: c#

I have a class of settings that are managed elsewhere, and many instances of worker classes that need to know the current values of settings relevant to themselves. Settings may change at any moment.

In C++ I can simply pass a reference to the relevant setting into the worker class constructor. How should I accomplish this in C#? Is reflection the only robust and concise solution?

The code below illustrates what I want to accomplish, but of course it fails because the value of the setting is copied at the moment the worker is instantiated. What options do I have for getting the values at the moment they are needed?

**How can I modify this code to achieve the desired behavior without making a mess?**

```
using System;
namespace TestSettings
{
    public static class Settings
    {
        public static bool setting1 { get; set; } = true;
        public static bool setting2 { get; set; } = false;
    }
    public class mWorker
    {
        private string wName;
        private bool wSetting;
        public mWorker(string _name, bool _setting)
        {
            wName = _name;
            wSetting = _setting;
        }
        public void doWork()
        {
            var onOff = (wSetting) ? "ON" : "OFF";
            Console.WriteLine($"Worker {wName} is turned {onOff}");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Settings are passed by value when each worker is 
            // instantiated. I want to pass the constructor   
            // something that allows each setting to be read 
            // dynamically whenever it is used. 
            mWorker worker1 = new mWorker("W1", Settings.setting1);
            mWorker worker2 = new mWorker("W2", Settings.setting2);

            Console.WriteLine("\n=====================");
            worker1.doWork();   // Result: "Worker W1 is turned ON"
            worker2.doWork();   // Result: "Worker W2 is turned OFF"

            Settings.setting1 = false;
            Settings.setting2 = true;

            Console.WriteLine("\n=====================");
            worker1.doWork();   // Desired result: "Worker W1 is turned OFF"
            worker2.doWork();   // Desired result: "Worker W2 is turned ON"
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I've read many SO questions and answers about workarounds for the fact that properties cannot be passed by reference, and there are lots of hints and suggestions, but none of them have answered my question in any way that I can translate into a decision and a working solution. I went back to John Skeet's C# book and reread it, and I'm sure the answer is in there somewhere -- but I still don't see it.

I know I could pass a property name and use reflection to get the value. Magic strings make me uncomfortable, but perhaps NameOf() would make that OK.  I know I could create a class of named settings and write a function to return the value given the setting name. I understand that delegates might be able to help, but the examples I've seen appear to require a delegate per setting, and I'm hoping for a concise solution.

I assume I could give up properties and use public fields, passing a reference to the field, but a number of smart people on SO have recommended against that approach in questions that are similar (but not identical) to mine.

I can't help feeling that this must be a commonly needed bit of functionality, and hoping there is a **generally accepted approach** for handling it in C#.

Comment: why not simply make setting1 a field (which is what you would do in c++)

Comment: I believe there should only be one setting ` public class Settings { public bool MySetting { get; set; }; }` and then you pass these two different instances of the settings class into the workers. Full working example in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to keep Settings class as is, you could do something like this:

```
public static class Settings
{
    public static bool setting1 { get; set; } = true;
    public static bool setting2 { get; set; } = false;
}

public class mWorker
{
    private string wName;
    private Func<bool> wSetting;

    public mWorker(string _name, Func<bool> _setting)
    {
        wName = _name;
        wSetting = _setting;
    }
    public void doWork()
    {
        var onOff = wSetting() ? "ON" : "OFF";
        Console.WriteLine($"Worker {wName} is turned {onOff}");
    }
}

class Program
{
    void Main()
    {
        // Settings are passed by value when each worker is 
        // instantiated. I want to pass the constructor   
        // something that allows each setting to be read 
        // dynamically whenever it is used. 
        mWorker worker1 = new mWorker("W1", () => Settings.setting1);
        mWorker worker2 = new mWorker("W2", () => Settings.setting2);

        Console.WriteLine("\n=====================");
        worker1.doWork();   // Result: "Worker W1 is turned ON"
        worker2.doWork();   // Result: "Worker W2 is turned OFF"

        Settings.setting1 = false;
        Settings.setting2 = true;

        Console.WriteLine("\n=====================");
        worker1.doWork();   // Result: "Worker W1 is turned OFF"
        worker2.doWork();   // Result: "Worker W2 is turned ON"

    }
}
```

Comment: In fact I do need to keep the settings class as it is, since there are hundreds of settings of many different data types, most of which are bound to external physical devices and are shared by multiple workers. This answer is simple, terse, and elegant, with the advantage that it can be applied to the given code sample with a minimum of disturbance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a reference type to the constructor. You can create a class for your setting and use an instance that you would update.

```html
public class Setting 
{
    public bool isActive { get; set; }
}

public static class Settings
{
    public static Setting setting1 { get; set; } = new Setting { isActive = true };
    public static Setting setting2 { get; set; } = new Setting { isActive = false };
}
public class mWorker
{
    private string wName;
    private Setting wSetting;
    public mWorker(string _name, Setting _setting)
    {
        wName = _name;
        wSetting = _setting;
    }
    public void doWork()
    {
        var onOff = wSetting.isActive ? "ON" : "OFF";
        Console.WriteLine($"Worker {wName} is turned {onOff}");
    }
}
```

Comment: While this works if you introduce `worker3` you would need to add `settings3` which would be a code change. With your solution I suggest just passing a  `Setting` (no 's') object to the worker. (That's essentially what my answer shows).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a more c# friendly way for you example.

Instead of having setting1 and setting2 I used two different instances of a Settings class.

```
    public class Settings: ISettings
    {
        public bool MySetting { get; set; }
    }
```

When you add `worker3`, in your design, you would need to add `setting3`. With the design shown here you don't need to modify the `Settings` class.

Here is the code (the interface part is not necessary, but allows for easy mocking later and it's a good habit)

The result of running this code is

[image]

```
    public interface ISettings
    {
        bool MySetting { get; set; }
    }

    public class Settings: ISettings
    {
        public bool MySetting { get; set; } = true;
    }
    public class mWorker
    {
        private string wName;
        private ISettings settings;
        public mWorker(string _name, ISettings settings)
        {
            wName = _name;
            this.settings = settings;
        }
        public void doWork()
        {
            var onOff = (settings.MySetting) ? "ON" : "OFF";
            Console.WriteLine($"Worker {wName} is turned {onOff}");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var settingsForWorker1 = new Settings() { MySetting = true };
            mWorker worker1 = new mWorker("W1", settingsForWorker1);
            var settingsForWorker2 = new Settings() { MySetting = false };
            mWorker worker2 = new mWorker("W2", settingsForWorker2);

            Console.WriteLine("\n=====================");
            worker1.doWork();   // Result: "Worker W1 is turned ON"
            worker2.doWork();   // Result: "Worker W2 is turned OFF"

            settingsForWorker1.MySetting = false;
            settingsForWorker2.MySetting = true;

            Console.WriteLine("\n=====================");
            worker1.doWork();   // Desired result: "Worker W1 is turned OFF"
            worker2.doWork();   // Desired result: "Worker W2 is turned ON"
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

If you store the settings in a collection then it's very easy to managed them for an arbitrary number of workers:

```
var settings = new Dictionary<string, Settings>()
{
    { "W1", new Settings() { MySetting = true } },
    { "W2", new Settings() { MySetting = false } },
    { "W3", new Settings() { MySetting = false } },
};

mWorker worker1 = new mWorker("W1", settings["W1"]);
mWorker worker2 = new mWorker("W2", settings["W2"]);

(...)
```

Comment: Very helpful concepts! I probably oversimplified by simply saying the settings are "managed elsewhere," because in reality there are hundreds of preexisting settings (some value types and some reference types) that are bound to external devices and are shared across workers that typically have many settings in common.